# How to use angularjs inline filter to compare complete value of a key in a json array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have a JSON array and want to filter out some elements from in it based on a matching criteria.

**{{ myJsonArray | filter : { myKey : myValue } }}**

The problem with the inline filter in AngularJS is that it does not compare the full value of the key supplied, instead it compares the part of the value from the array.

I dont see any other alternative to inline filter that I can use within HTML.

```
//My Json Array
$scope.myJsonArray = [
 { id : 1, myKey : "5" },
 { id : 2, myKey : "10" },
 { id : 3, myKey : "15" },
 { id : 4, myKey : "20" }
];
```

```
{{ (myJsonArray | filter : { myKey : 1 }).length }}
```

I except the output to be 0 as the value supplied to myKey does not exist in any of the Json object within the array.

**But the actual output appears to be 2.**

The reason is because the angularjs filter compares the supplied value 1 with 10 and 15 and returns true as 1 do exist in these keys.

I want the filter to compare the key as a single complete value and not as a part of the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working one: https://plnkr.co/edit/a9LR7lWpgluzufUZTzUF?p=preview

you are expecting the strict eqality, So use below solution

```
{{ (myJsonArray | filter : { myKey : '15' }:true).length }}
```

Look at the :true at the end, which is used to specify strict comparison.

```
{ myKey : '15' }:true
```

Refer https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.10/docs/api/ng/filter/filter and look at comparator(3rd argument) in the documentation